# По какому принципу Java-метод `getResource` ищет файлы?

Tags: java, javafx

В моём JavaFX приложении произошла распространённая ошибка `"Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set."`. Она вызвана это строкой:

```java
FXML_Loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/views/RootLayout.fxml"));
```

Чтобы бегать каждый раз на форум при возникновении данной ошибки, нужно понять, по какому принципу метод `getResource` ищет файлы. Я так думаю, он преобразует параметр в абсолютный путь к файлу, а ошибка произошла потому, что этот метод либо не понял, относительно чего нужно генерировать абсолютный путь, либо сгенерировал его неправильно.

Для большей конкретики разобью свой вопрос на три подвопроса:

1. Относительно чего будет сгенерирован абсолютный путь к "RootLayout.fxml"?
2. Как изменить эту базовую директорию?
3. Какие существуют стандартные подходы в Java для организации статических файлов и обеспечения доступа к ним? (Если ответ на этот подвопрос будет длинным, то ссылка на статью по этой теме вполне подойдёт)

Comment: В зависимости от указанного в кавычках, будет искать в ресурсной папке относительно корня `/views/RootLayout.fxml` либо в ресурсной папке относительно местоположения `getClass + /views/RootLayout.fxml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще это довольно сложный вопрос.

1. В идеальном мире `getResource()` ищет ресурсы в `CLASSPATH`, если быть точнее отправляет запрос к загрузчику классов, который собственно и ищет в `CLASSPATH`
2. В реальном мире, положение `resource` задается билдером, например если вы под `maven`, то положение `resource` можно задавать примерно так:

   ```
   <resources>
       <resource>
           <directory>src/fx/resources</directory>
       </resource>
   </resources>
   ```
3. В gradle по умолчанию предполагается, что `resource` лежит в каталоге  `src/main/resources` его также можно задавать менять самому (погуглите)
4. Корень относительно которого ищется ресурс показывает как раз на каталог `resource`, на который показывает билдер/загрузчик классов.
5. Если корень не указан, то есть имя ресурса не начинается с `/`, то ресурс ищется в каталоге состоящем из имени пакета класса - типа: `my/class/package/name/`

[документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Благодарю Вас за канонический ответ!